# ASP.NET Core 3.1 + Azure AD Authentication - How to disclose "hidden email"

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, azure-active-directory

I have an ASP.NET Core MVC web application using Azure AD as authentication method.

When somebody not assigned to this app is trying to login, an error `"Message contains error: 'access_denied', error_description: 'AADSTS50105: The signed in user '**{EmailHidden}**' is not assigned to a role for the application (...)"` is generated.

In the context of `OpenIdConnectEvents.OnRemoteFailure`, I would like to be able to access the real value of **{EmailHidden}** in order to improve logging of unauthorized access

I already tried to configure `IdentityModelEventSource.ShowPII = true` in the app `ConfigureServices` method. It solved other similar problem but not this one.

Any idea / suggestion ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

This error typically happens when the Enterprise Application portion (or Service Principal) of the registered application has the setting `User Assignment Required` set to `Yes`.

[image]

You can follow the steps below to work around this issue:

1.Change the `User assignment required` to `No` and save the change.
2.Go back to the App Registration portal and perform `Granting Admin consent to the application`. It should work this time.
3.Set the `User assignment required` back to Yes again.

Comment: Thanks but was not really my question :) I know why it does happen, I did enable the setting you highlighted above on purpose. But I would like to be able to trace the real user id in logs when it happens, not get this {EmailHiden}. My question is to know to disable this obfuscation.